# How to create sevenly.org like design using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have basic knowledge of javascript and jquery . I want to implement design like [Sevenly](http://www.sevenly.org) which is like a page/div is move over another but I don't know how to start with that . Let me know if anyone has as idea on how to implement this ?

Comment: You should learn to use the browsers' developer tools. This will help you to inspect HTML, CSS and JavaScript of websites.

Comment: I used firebug and they have used section tags which I think is from html 5 and I don't want to use them. Anyway thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first container has a specific height, then I think the most straight forward solution would be to fix the first container (`position:fixed`). Then you add a `margin-top` to the rest to push the rest down so it starts just below the first container:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="rest">
    <div>Other 1</div>
    <div>Other 2</div>
    <div>Other 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header{ 
    position:absolute;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    border: 2px dashed yellow; 
    background-color: lightyellow; 
}
div#rest{
    margin-top:150px;
    position:relative;
}  
div#rest div{    
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px dashed green;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

The `position:absolute;` is for browsers that don't support fixed. Making it absolute will causes it to behave like fixed, except that it scrolls along with the rest of the page. The `position:relative;` on the rest is because of z-stacking. `fixed`-ing the header container causes it to be put in it's own layer on top of everything else; setting the rest to `relative` puts the rest on top of the header again.

[See jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wBCMY/).

If you don't have a specific height on the header, then you will probably need to use javascript.

Comment: Well your solution almost worked butwhy the div#header is always coming behind the div#rest ?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. The header comes behind the rest because the rest has `position:relative`. That is by design. If you remove `position:relative`, then the header will be on top instead (and the rest will move up below it when you scroll).

Comment: leave it . I will figure it out. Thanks for solution.